# How can I view a database table using psql?

Tags: sql, database, command-line, psql

I am currently SSH'ed into my universities computers, and I am using psql. So far I have only connected to the database. How can I view tables in there? Is there a way I can make the terminal print out a table in text?

Comment: with `\d` you can see the tables. And to see a table just `SELECT * FROM table;`.

Comment: This only shows me the types and columns in the tables, not the actual values. Is there a way to see the values too?

Comment: `select * from the_table` **will** show you the "values" - you really need to read a tutorial: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-select.html

Comment: I tried that but the command line doesn't return anything, it just goes to new input as if I pressed enter without typing anything, like this:
my_database=>SELECT * FROM table_name
*presses enter*
my_database=>

Comment: The `;` in the end of an SQL sentence is important in psql. If no `;` is present it won't work.

Comment: thank you so much! Arghh so annoying how simple that was